# Joining multiple tables and using AliasToBean Transformer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have **6 different tables** and the first table has a **child table** and the second table is the parent for the second one(First to second tables all one to many relationships). So this continues to 6 tables. Something like the main table would be college and child will be Student and then for Student we have Subject as child tables and for Subject, we have chapters to as a child.

Can some help me with an example of how can I map this multiple join query to a BO using AlisastoBaean transformer. The reason I am going with this approach is that

1) I have these tables used everywhere and cannot use lazy or eager loading

2) I just require two or 3 columns form each table.

3) And few columns have clob data type.

Comment: join query to a BO. What is BO?

Comment: list all 6 table with relation. Then we can see. or else do @Query() for join